# Account Name in Opportunity custom object

Tags: opportunity, formula-field

I'm trying to create a custom field on Opportunity object with account name. Can I use a formula to populate it automatically?

I tried creating the custom field of type `Text` and adding `Account.Name` in formula, but it says `Field Account does not exist. Check spelling`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a custom field with type Formula, and your Account.Name will work perfectly.

I suspect you are creating a field with the type of Text, and using this formula in the default value section. This will not work, as you can tell. If you would like this field to be a text field that is editable, you can create a workflow that will populate the Account Name.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

"Opportunity custom object" - if its not the standard opportunity object, your account field is not `Account`, its probably something like `Account__r.Name` instead.

Make sure you are creating a new Formula field, with the type text, and not a text field with a default value. The latter will never change after you set the value, while a formula fields value is dynamic, and will update whenever requested from the database.

You need to check the field & use its API Name. The system helps you get the right field names using the formula editor, theres a section to insert a field, which will use the right name.

[image]

[image]

If you dont see the field your looking for in that menu, you have a different problem. Some details about your object & the relationships could go a long way here.